# Restore deleted Chrome Profile on Macbook?

Tags: google-chrome, google

I accidentally deleted a Chrome Profile and it is worth VERY much to me! **I have no google sync or computer backup.** Is there a software I can use to get it back, I do not care if it's expensive, just need it back!?

Comment: If on a SSD then probaly not. Even if there is a way the you needed to stop using that disk immediately, as it is if you are still using that disk e.g. in writing the question then it will have been overidden. I suggest that the next thing toiy do is set up a backup regeme.

Comment: I would like a answer to " Even if there is a way"... Better to try than not.

Comment: If the machine has a Hard Disk then try DiskWorrier but again that is likely only to work if you have stopped using your computer immediately after the deletion.

Comment: @mmmmmm Do you know where I set the search at? chrome folder or?

Comment: How did you delete it if by Finder then look in the Trash/Bin

Comment: @mmmmmm I deleted it inside of chrome in profiles. I had three profiles and I accidentally removed wrong profile.